# Iterating through an array 2 items at a time

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I have a string array that looks something like `["a","b","c","d"]`. Each two consecutive items are pairs and I want to iterate through the array and be able to consider the two strings together. Currently I'm thinking of having a loop and a count to work out where I am in the iteration but is there a simpler/better way?

Comment: Some possibilities that come to mind: a map of pairs, an array of arrays, an object representing a pair, incrementing the count by two instead of one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for (int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i+=2) {
    String first = a[i];
    String second = a[i+1];
    ...
}
```

**Note!** If the array is provided by a caller, then you might want to add some extra code to handle the case where `a.length` is not even.

Answer (score 4):

So I assume you mean `a -> b` and `c -> d`. The classic way to deal with this is a loop that increments two at a time:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i += 2) {
    final String firstVal = myArray[i];
    final String secondVal = myArray[i + 1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few possibilities.

1)

```
class PairString {
    String a;
    String b;
}
PairString[] stringPairs;
```

2)

```
while (i < array.length) {
    String a = array[i];
    String b = array[i + 1];
    i += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using some math?

```
final String[] words = { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "42" };
final int n = words.length / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(words[i * 2] + "-" + words[(i * 2) + 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the loop that increments two at a time as well, but just to add something a little different, you could also make use of `IntStream`:

```
final String[] words = { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "42" };
IntStream.range(1, words.length).forEach(i -> System.out.println(words[i-1] + words[i]));
```

Outputs:

```
FooBar
BarBaz
Baz42
```