# Java Iterate over List in pairs each 2 elements

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I have an `ArrayList` and I want to iterate over it each 2 elements, like this: ([1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6])

Currently I'm able to iterate the list like this: ([1,2], [2, 3], [3, 4]) but this is not the result I want.

Here is my code:

```
Iterator<MyObject> iterator = myList.iterator();
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            MyObject o1 = iterator.next();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                final MyObject o2 = iterator.next();
                //Do my stuff
                o1 = o2;
            }
        }
```

I know that should be quite simple but I don't see it.

I got the code from this link: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453022/idiom-for-pairwise-iteration-through-a-sorted-collection)

I've also seen these post:

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033711/java-iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465223/iterating-through-an-array-2-items-at-a-time)

Comment: Those questions you have also seen answer this perfectly well.

Comment: @Enzokie if the list contains zero elements we don't do anything, if it contains 1 element we only take that element

Comment: Why the negative votes? I have said that I have tried the solutions from the links I have indicated. Maybe the solution is there but for some reason I don't get it working. Probably I'm stupid but I don't think that's a reason to down vote my question

Comment: Do you specifically want to use an iterator?

Comment: @asiew not specifically, but with the iterator I don't need to worry about going over the list size. But not, I don't need to use the iterator

Comment: @Ale The second and third questions you linked to gave answers to this question. If they didn't work for you, tell us what you tried and why they didn't work. Otherwise there's nothing we can say that wasn't said in answer to those other questions.

Comment: @khelwood thanks for the advise, if you say my solution is there I'll try the given solutions one more time. Thanks to all who gave an answer and tried to help instead of down voting the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i+=2) {
    list.get(i);
    list.get(i+1);
}
```

In that you have to check if you don't go over size of list.